# How to change the button class from btn-default to btn-success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this select multiple box with option as button.

```
<select multiple class="form-control" onchange="selectedIds(this)" >
                            <option value="" onclick="selectUnselect(this)" class="btn btn-default">
                                option1
                            </option>
                        </select>
```

Through jQuery i am changing the button class on click

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".form-control option").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('btn')) {
        $(this).toggleClass('btn-success');
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass('btn-default');
    }
});
```

});

I want to change the selected option's button color to green e.g `btn btn-success` class from `btn btn-default` and when the user again clicks on the selected option it should go back to the initial color i.e `btn btn-default`

Clicking on the single option is working fine but when I select multiple options the top color of the previous button becomes blue,
like this

[image],

The live app is here: https://i2a.herokuapp.com/app/questionnaire/create/

in safari, the option is not coming as a button but in Chrome it's coming as buttons

Could anyone help me to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please provide your **full** code

Comment: @GalAbra it's written as Django template. If you would like to see it I could make a snippet of the full code.

Comment: @GalAbra https://gist.github.com/triump0870/b724824cf6d0de4a92bcb3331c36dea4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the first condition will be always true, because `.btn` will always be on the element. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".form-control option").click(function () {
       $(this).toggleClass('btn-success');
       $(this).toggleClass('btn-default');
   }
);
```

On the first click, it will remove `.btn-default` class and add `.btn-success` class. On second click it will do the opposite.

Comment: But that blue color is not disappearing from second button click onwards

Comment: Can you paste CSS styles for that `select`?

Comment: you can check the webpage here https://i2a.herokuapp.com/app/questionnaire/create/

Comment: That blue or gray background color is coming from default browser behavior. I think it's not a good idea to use `select` this way. I would rather use buttons as checkboxes (read more https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons).